# How to read a JSON file from SASS?

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

I'm working in Angular using Webpack 2. I need to create sass variables to specify the path of some images and filling their values at runtime from a JS or JSON configuration file stored in the root, in this way the path can be configured at the  installation step as:

```sass
$get-path-to-base: ""; // loading from external config.

.my-class {
   background: url(#{$get-path-to-base}/images/save.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you described you are using `node-sass` then luckily you have [node-sass-json-importer](https://github.com/Updater/node-sass-json-importer) which allow you import JSON in SASS files parsed by `node-sass`.

In their GitHub page you can see [instructions for Webpack](https://github.com/Updater/node-sass-json-importer#webpack--sass-loader).

Cheers!

Comment: OK thanks. I understand that i cant do it runtime but I will follow your suggestion to do it from webpack